# Nested form keeps creating new forms instead of overwriting previous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a nested form that I render in my Submission show view that is meant to show a status field and notes field. This seems to be working fine, however whenever I navigate to the show view, it seems to show the current Status and Notes fields as well as creating additional Status and Notes fields. I would just like it to show one status and notes field that can be overwritten with new data.

Current form being rendered:

```
<%= form_for @submission do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :agent_activities do |a|%>

      <td> <div class="field">

        <%= a.text_field :Status%>

      </div>
    </td>

    <td> <div class="field">

      <%= a.text_field :Notes %>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
</td>
<% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Submission Controller:

```
def show
@submission.agent_activities.build
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

This is a pluralized statement:

```
 <%= f.fields_for :agent_activities do |a|%>
```

Needed to be singular like this,

```
<%= f.fields_for :agent_activity do |a|%>
```